# How to show "0" as default instead of "Null" in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I want to get 0 instead of null in my select query.

I mean currently my query is showing NULL for amount column if there are no entry in table.

Can I get 0 for amount column in select query if it has NULL?

Comment: It depends on the query, but ISNULL will work most of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select isnull(column,0)
```

> Can I get 0 for amount column in select query if it has NULL?

Yes you can get. If you will show your exact table and column name then it would be the best else you can try like this:-

```
select isnull(amount,0) as Amount from MyTable
```

**On a side note:-**

You may also check out about **[ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLCOLUMN1, 0) NULLCOLUMN1
```